# LIKE operator issue in Ignite

Tags: sql-like, ignite

We are trying to execute the following select queries with LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM u24_166004_ltb 
where customer_id like ('%059') 
ORDER BY id asc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1012 ROWS ONLY
```

There are records in the table where customer_id endsWith ('059') but still the query returns empty set.

```
SELECT * FROM u24_166004_ltb 
where customer_id like ('%9') 
ORDER BY id asc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1012 ROWS ONLY
```

This query returns correct results.

The LIKE operator is not working as expected everytime. Why is it so? Is LIKE operator fully supported in Ignite? Is there any equivalent for LIKE operator in Ignite?

Please go through the enclosed attachment for more details. The attachment clearly shows records that end with ('059').

[image: Result for LIKE with (%9) query]

Regards, 
Shravya Nethula.

Comment: You might want to include some sample data in your question.

Comment: Why are you putting parentheses around the argument to `LIKE`?  `LIKE` is not a function in SQL.  Try this: `SELECT * FROM u24_166004_ltb WHERE customer_id LIKE '%059'`

Comment: The following is the sample data from the table:

Query:
SELECT id, customer_id, quantity FROM u24_166004_ltb limit 10

ID, CUSTOMER_ID,  QUANTITY
1041, 1000005059, 16
1073, 1000048059, 24
1089, 1000012059, 210
1105, 1000005059, 1
1121, 1000048059, 3
1137, 1000048059, 8
1153, 1000048059, 400
1169, 1000005059, 608
1201, 1000012059,  2
1233, 1000005059,  3

Comment: SELECT * FROM u24_166004_ltb WHERE customer_id LIKE '%059'
I have tried this query and it is still returning empty result set.

Comment: I have tried it on 2.7 and I can get both queries to return all results.